# Migrate data from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, upgrade, migration, magento2-migration-tool

Best way to Migrate data from Magento 1 to Magento 2. I found below tools provided by Magento and some third party but don't know exactly which one to follow and what is the best way.

Magento tool: `http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate-data.html`

Third party tool:  `https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/`

> We need only the Data migration like order,products,customers,store
>   configuration etc.

We did upgrade with third party tool but getting issues at store view level data at Magento admin side.

Any references or suggestion are highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Data Migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2 is a bit technical if you are a newbie or a new Magento learner. You can start the migration process by installing the [Magento 2 Data Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool) via composer.

To install this tool, make sure that the version of Magento 2 and Data Migration Tool matches exactly. For example, if you are using Magento v2.1.2, you must install Data Migration Tool v2.1.2.

If you are worried about the version of your Magento 2, you can find it out by navigating to the root directory of your Magento 2 via SSH terminal and enter the following command:

```
php bin/magento --version
```

Now, once you know the version of your Magento 2 store, you can now install the Data Migration Tool. I am sharing 2 CLI commands with you. The 1st command will update the location of the Data Migration Tool package in the composer.json file and the 2nd command will install the tool in your Magento 2 store. Run the following commands to carry out this job:

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<version>
```

In the above CLI command, `<version>` refers to the version of Data Migration Tool which must match with the Magento 2 version discovered earlier. For example, if you are using Magento 2.1.2, enter the exact below commands:

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.2
```

You will be asked to enter your authentication keys. Go to [Magento Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/). Sign in using your login credentials, click My Access Keys and get your public and private key. After that within few seconds, the Data Migration Tool will be successfully installed on your Magento 2 store.

After the installation, the following directories will contain mapping and configuration files for the Data Migration Tool:

> Magento 2 root dir/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce

contains configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Community Edition to Magento 2 Community Edition, and

> Magento 2 root dir/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ee

contains configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Community Edition to Magento 2 Enterprise Edition, and

> Magento 2 root dir/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ee-to-ee

contains configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Enterprise Edition to Magento 2 Enterprise Edition.

Before you migrate any settings and data, you must create a `config.xml` file in the relevant directory. For example, if you are performing data migration from Magento 1 CE to Magento 2 CE, navigate to the `Magento 2 root dir/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/<Magento 1.x version>` directory and rename `config.xml.dist` to `config.xml`.

Next, open `config.xml` in a code editor and specify the following:

```
<source>
<database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</source>
<destination>
<database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</destination>
<options>
<crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>
</options>
```

In the above code, `<source>` has the database information of Magento 1 and `<destination>` has the relevant information of Magento 2. `<crypt_key>` is mandatory to fill in. It is the encryption key of Magento 1 which can be found in `Magento 1 root dir/app/etc/local.xml` file in `<key>` tag.

When finished, save the `config.xml` and you are done!

Now, To migrate the settings, navigate to your Magento 2 root directory via SSH terminal and run the following command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset <path to your config.xml>
```

where `<path to your config.xml>` this would be `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/<Magento 1.x version>/config.xml`. I have also used `--reset` argument in the above command which forces the Data Migration Tool to start from the beginning.

And finally, to migrate data, run the following CLI command:

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset <path to your config.xml>
```

As this command runs, the Data Migration Tool saves its current progress, and in the case of any errors, stops the process and resumes the progress from the last known good state. Also, the Data Migration Tool may report some errors during the migration. I advise you to refer the [Troubleshooting page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-troubleshooting.html) of the Data Migration Tool for further assistance.

Once the data migration is completed, you will receive a success message. For further reference, you can visit the below blog post:

[How To Migrate From Magento 1 To Magento 2](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/)

Comment: I am getting this error

[Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

where do u define tables prefix

Answer (score 1):

You can Data migration like order, products, customers by Magento tool.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate-data.html

Follow this link for migration. I have completed migration by this link.

If you will face any issue with this, you can share with me.

I will help you.

Comment: @patel thanks for your answer, sure will try and post you any error if found.

Comment: I am getting invalid config file name error

Comment: hi @Suresh. I am getting below error "Invalid parameter configuration provided for $sourceDocument argument of Migration\RecordTransformer"

Answer (score 0):

The long-awaited Magento 2.0 has been released a few days ago. There is a vast difference in the file structure of Magento 2.x and Magento 1.x, so it’s not possible to upgrade to the 2.0 version like we used to in 1.x version. Though the awesome Magento Community has developed such tools which can help you migrate data from your Magento store from 1.x to 2.x versions. You can’t upgrade the Magento theme to 2.0 but you can at least perform data migration.

Follow this link how to Migrate data from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x using a migration tool.

https://magecomp.com/blog/migrating-magento-1-x-to-magento-2-0/

Comment: thanks for your feedback, but it seems you have shared the same tool which ubertheme is providing. Did you tried this tool and any feed back on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free extension for migration :

```
https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-extensions-2-x/magento-2-data-migration-tool/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want import data order,products,customers... i think you can use some extension

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-import-export-categories-extension.html

http://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/export-import

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you choose the migration tool offerred by Magento:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate-data.html

It worked very well with my Magento 2.0.3 website in the past.

If you don't have much technical skill, you can hire a developer/expert to do this for you. This's one of the most reliable migration service I have worked with, you could try contacting them for the migration, they will perform the migration and help you fix other problems in your Magento 2 store: [Magento 1 to Magento 2 migration service](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/).

> Magento database is designed in complex EAV structure, so it's not
>   easy to perform the migration without issues. Don't forget to create a
>   backup of your Magento 2 store before the migration.