# Magento 1 migration to magento V-2.2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, migration, transfer

I would like to migrate from `Magento V-1.x to Magento V-2.x` using an index.php instead of the composer.json.

Is there any helpful links, pages, or tips on how to do such a `migration`.

I was reading and reviewing online that there is but I can't get my index.php file to work **I get a 500 error**.

Comment: which version index you got 505  ? on magento 2 or Magento 1

Comment: i tried to share the points which i faced during this process of migration hope it help you to migrate the data easily , rest depends on your current Magento 1 store

Answer (score 1):

Always Switch to Developer Mode
Q How to switch to `Developer Mode Using Command Line`?

Run below command at root of your M2 installation.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

`This will help you to debug the 500 error as well`

Data Migration is not an easy process but Magento community already trying there best to make this process smooth.

Link to read the [Data Migration Tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool.html)

> Note: Data Migration tool can be downloaded by composer or from GitHub 
>   if you installed your Magento 2  using composer than must install Migration tool using the composer only.

To download Github [Magento Data Migration Tool](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool) if you installed magento 2 from repository.

**Step 0 :** While this process usually max execution time or memory limit became a headache so its good to increase those limits for the time being

Q .How to find the php.ini path ?

```
php -v | grep "php.ini"
```

`In php.ini Increase the memory limit in your .php.ini file`

```
 ;adjust memory limit  
    memory_limit = 1G  
    max_execution_time = 36000  
    max_input_time = 36000
```

**Step 1 :** Install fresh Magento 2 using composer or from repo

**step 2:** Install Data Migration Tool as per the above conditions
You may install the Data Migration Tool from:

1. repo.magento.com

   composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
   composer require magento/data-migration-tool:

Here  is the version of Magento 2 you installed

2. GitHub  ( you can install this one )

**step 3:** [Configure migration](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html)

**step 4:** follow these steps [Migrate using Data Migration Tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate.html)

> Note : [Data that needs to be migrated manually](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-manually.html)

**There are some SE question on same which will be helpful if you stuck in same situations**

1) [Migrate data from Magento 1 to Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147557/migrate-data-from-magento-1-to-magento-2)

2) [Magento 2 Migration Tool - Verify if Migration is successful from 1.9 - 2.0 CE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101369/magento-2-migration-tool-verify-if-migration-is-successful-from-1-9-2-0-ce?rq=1)

3) [Get error when running php bin/magento setup:di:compile](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151715/get-error-when-running-php-bin-magento-setupdicompile?rq=1)

Source :

1. [Memory Limit](https://www.measureddesigns.com/magento-2-allowed-memory-size-exhausted/)
2. [Creating a migration plan](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-plan.html)
3. [Common error messages](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-troubleshooting.html)